# Lua script performance using local variable initialized to math.huge, or just using math.huge directly

Tags: lua

Would it be better to create a local "Infinity" var initialized to math.huge, or have math.huge just appear in the Lua script wherever something is compared with "Infinity"?

```
local Infinity = math.huge
local someVar = 999999
local output = nil
if someVar < Infinity then
  output = 0.666
else
  output = -1
end
print(output)
```

or

```
local someVar = 999999
local output = nil
if someVar < math.huge then
  output = 0.666
else
  output = -1
end
print(output)
```

Assuming the actual Lua script is much bigger with many comparisons with Infinity.
Or is there no difference at all (in which case I'd go with using math.huge directly to save a local variable)?

Comment: Looks like premature optimization.

Answer (score 0):

LuaJIT does that automatically and is therefore not recommended. (based on what I read and tested, if anyone has a proper source please comment)

Lua alone, however, [states](https://www.lua.org/pil/4.2.html) that locals are faster.

I did a small benchmark, 1 Billion iterations, your code, bundled Lua in Zerobrane Studio, values in seconds.

|  | Lua 5.2 | Lua 5.3 | LuaJit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Global | 21.48 | 24.86 | 0.25 |
| Local | 9.31 | 12.04 | 0.25 |

Even tho the code is unusually small and may not reflect real code, the results are clear. Still, don't waste time on premature optimizations if you don't plan to use `math.huge` a lot.